# Assigning a visit number to rows in a database?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tried searching around with no luck, maybe I'm just not using right the terminology. Anyway, I'm working with a postgresql 8.1 database (redshift) where a sample of the data would look like this:

```
User ID   Timestamp    Visit ID
1         05:20:20am   10
2         05:21:00am   11
1         05:22:14am   12
1         05:24:09am   13
```

Let's say this is a very basic sample of the data. I want to do analysis on how people do on other metrics when its their 1st visit, 2nd visit, 3rd visit, etc. The easiest way I can think to do this would be to create either a seperate table that looks like:

```
Visit ID    Visit Number
10          1
11          1
12          2 
13          3
```

Or somehow appending to my original table:

```
User ID   Timestamp    Visit ID    Visit Number
1         05:20:20am   10          1
2         05:21:00am   11          1 
1         05:22:14am   12          2
1         05:24:09am   13          3
```

I know I can use groupby and count to anaylze performance for those visitors who came at least x amount of times vs those that came less. However, I don't know how to anaylze performance on the first, second, third visit, especially when users could have visited anywhere from 1-50,000 times.

So an example question I'd like to answer... for users who visit at least 10 times, do they perform better on their first 5 visits or their 2nd five?

Very much appreciate the advice, this site is wonderful.

Thanks.

Comment: Assuming that you added a field (column) to your original table (your 2nd suggestion) please provide how you want to see **the result** (you will need to add more rows).

Answer (score 1):

One (potentially slow) option is to use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT  t.UserID, 
        t.Timestamp, 
        t.VisitID,
        (   SELECT  COUNT(*) + 1
            FROM    T T2
            WHERE   T2.UserID = T.UserID
            AND     T2.TimeStamp < T.TimeStamp
        ) VisitNumber
FROM    T;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!10/6aee6/2)**

The easiest (although possibly not viable) solution would be to upgrade to Postgresql 8.4 or later and take advantage of ROW_NUMBER:

```
SELECT  t.UserID, 
        t.Timestamp, 
        t.VisitID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.UserID ORDER BY t.Timestamp) AS VisitNumber
FROM    T;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/6aee6/1)**

Finally, if the first query is too slow, and upgrading is not an option the following article goes into some detail about a further alternative. I have no idea how this will perform though.

http://www.depesz.com/2007/08/17/rownum-anyone-cumulative-sum-in-one-query/