# Assigning a visit number to rows in a data frame using R

Tags: r, reshape2

I'm working with a large database of bird occurrence and abundance observations in a data frame in R. We visited each survey point multiple times across multiple years and entered a row with a bird code for every bird we saw. We tell visits to the same point apart using a combination of year and julian day. A simplified version of my database:

```
pointid year    jul_day alpha   ct
EL_1    2010    112     NESP    3
EL_1    2010    112     RWBL    4
EL_1    2010    112     SALS    5
EL_1    2010    112     VIRA    2
EL_1    2010    119     LALO    6
EL_1    2010    119     RWBL    1
EL_1    2010    119     RWBL    1
EL_1    2010    119     SALS    1
EL_1    2010    119     SALS    5
EL_1    2010    119     TRES    3
EL_1    2011    203     VIRA    2
EL_2    2010    112     GREG    10
EL_2    2010    119     NESP    1
EL_2    2011    203     HAHA    1
EL_2    2012    132     BOBO    2
EL_2    2012    132     LALO    1
EL_2    2012    132     SNEG    4
EL_2    2012    145     YEWA    1
EL_2    2012    167     RNPH    5
EL_2    2013    111     RWBL    8
EL_2    2013    203     SALS    7
EL_3    2010    119     GREG    4
EL_3    2010    196     SALS    12
EL_3    2010    204     LALO    8
EL_3    2010    219     AMAV    1
EL_3    2010    234     BNST    1
EL_3    2014    223     CATE    2
```

I need to 1) count the number of visits to each point ID each year, and 2) assign a visit number (1,2,3,4,5) to each record within each year within 2 new columns (visit_num, and total_visits_within_year) appended to the data frame. Expected output would be something like:

```
pointid year    jul_day alpha   ct  v   visits_within_year
EL_1    2010    112     NESP    3   1   2
EL_1    2010    112     RWBL    4   1   2
EL_1    2010    112     SALS    5   1   2
EL_1    2010    112     VIRA    2   1   2
EL_1    2010    119     LALO    6   2   2
EL_1    2010    119     RWBL    1   2   2
EL_1    2010    119     RWBL    1   2   2
EL_1    2010    119     SALS    1   2   2
EL_1    2010    119     SALS    5   2   2
EL_1    2010    119     TRES    3   2   2
EL_1    2011    203     VIRA    2   1   1
EL_2    2010    112     GREG    10  1   2
EL_2    2010    119     NESP    1   2   2
EL_2    2011    203     HAHA    1   1   1
EL_2    2012    132     BOBO    2   2   4
EL_2    2012    132     LALO    1   2   4
EL_2    2012    132     SNEG    4   2   4
EL_2    2012    145     YEWA    1   3   4
EL_2    2012    167     RNPH    5   4   4
EL_2    2013    111     RWBL    8   1   2
EL_2    2013    203     SALS    7   2   2
EL_3    2010    119     GREG    4   1   5
EL_3    2010    196     SALS    12  2   5
EL_3    2010    204     LALO    8   3   5
EL_3    2010    219     AMAV    1   4   5
EL_3    2010    234     BNST    1   5   5
EL_3    2014    223     CATE    2   1   1
```

I am newly familiar with the reshape2 package but can't figure out how to apply either melt or dcast to this particular problem. This is similar to the sql question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19252468/assigning-a-visit-number-to-rows-in-a-database), however I need to count visits within year and assign a visit number within year in R, not sql. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Could you show the expected output for your input example?

Comment: @Marat - I've added expected output for my example and corrected a typo in the input. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the desired result with the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)

d %>% 
  group_by(year,pointid) %>% 
  mutate(v=as.numeric(as.factor(jul_day)), visits_within_year=max(v)) %>%
  print(n=50)

# Source: local data frame [27 x 7]
# Groups: year, pointid
# 
#    pointid year jul_day alpha ct v visits_within_year
# 1     EL_1 2010     112  NESP  3 1                  2
# 2     EL_1 2010     112  RWBL  4 1                  2
# 3     EL_1 2010     112  SALS  5 1                  2
# 4     EL_1 2010     112  VIRA  2 1                  2
# 5     EL_1 2010     119  LALO  6 2                  2
# 6     EL_1 2010     119  RWBL  1 2                  2
# 7     EL_1 2010     119  RWBL  1 2                  2
# 8     EL_1 2010     119  SALS  1 2                  2
# 9     EL_1 2010     119  SALS  5 2                  2
# 10    EL_1 2010     119  TRES  3 2                  2
# 11    EL_1 2011     203  VIRA  2 1                  1
# 12    EL_2 2010     112  GREG 10 1                  2
# 13    EL_2 2010     119  NESP  1 2                  2
# 14    EL_2 2011     203  HAHA  1 1                  1
# 15    EL_2 2012     132  BOBO  2 1                  3
# 16    EL_2 2012     132  LALO  1 1                  3
# 17    EL_2 2012     132  SNEG  4 1                  3
# 18    EL_2 2012     145  YEWA  1 2                  3
# 19    EL_2 2012     167  RNPH  5 3                  3
# 20    EL_2 2013     111  RWBL  8 1                  2
# 21    EL_2 2013     203  SALS  7 2                  2
# 22    EL_3 2010     119  GREG  4 1                  5
# 23    EL_3 2010     196  SALS 12 2                  5
# 24    EL_3 2010     204  LALO  8 3                  5
# 25    EL_3 2010     219  AMAV  1 4                  5
# 26    EL_3 2010     234  BNST  1 5                  5
# 27    EL_3 2014     223  CATE  2 1                  1
```

If you'd like to go with base R solution, you could rather use:

```
d2 <- d
d2$v <- ave(d2$jul_day,d2$year,d2$pointid,FUN=as.factor)
d2$visits_within_year <- ave(d2$v,d2$year,d2$pointid,FUN=function(z) if (length(z)==0) NULL else max(z))
```

Comment: Thank you! Hmm... as you know this works perfectly on my example dataset, however when I run this on my larger dataset the dplyr solution is throwing an Error: index out of bounds when I run the script. The base R solution is throwing Error in split.default(x, g) : group length is 0 but data length > 0. Any thoughts? I'll go down the rabbit hole of error explanations as well, but if you know any off the top of your head as applies here, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: which line of the base R solution throws the error?

Comment: Could you check if any  `split(d2$jul_day,d2$year)`,  `split(d2$jul_day,d2$pointid)`, and  `split(d2$jul_day,interaction(d2$year,d2$pointid)` throws the error?

Comment: I reran my code to clean the large database, and both the base R and dplyr code now work. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @MaratTalipov Could you please take a look at this question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28495965/what-cause-this-errorcould-not-find-function-fn-in-r?noredirect=1#comment45312608_28495965

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, if you load as a `data.table`, you should be able to:

```
DT[, sum(count), by=c('pointid', 'year')]
```

Comment: This seems to sum the total # of count records by year - since there are sometimes multiple bird records (rows) for a single visit (indicated by the same julian day and year combo), this unfortunately doesn't apply, unless I'm missing something.